# How to remove both instances of duplicated objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. I am trying to find duplicated objects and then remove both instances of that object.

Right now I am using this method:

```
function checkForDups(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++){
        if(data[j].number === data[i].number){
          data.splice(j,1);
          data.splice(i,1);
        }
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
```

I believe problem is that it only checks for duplicates that have an index that greater than the current position it is checking. This means objects that are "behind" it in the array are not checked for duplication. Currently I run the array through this function a few times to get the desired results. However, this is obviously extremely inefficient. How could I achieve my desired results more efficiently?

Comment: Can you please post an example array that yields unexpected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe problem is that it only checks for duplicates that have an index that greater than the current position it is checking. This means objects that are "behind" it in the array are not checked for duplication.

No, that's a simply optimisation, made possible by the symmetry of the equality relation. By searching ahead and removing all duplicates in front of you, any current item can't be a duplicate of a previous one or it would have been already eliminated.

However, there are some things you did not take care of:

- When splicing (removing) an item from the array, all subsequent ones are moved, and the array changes its length. To really examine all items in the array, you need decrease (or: not increase) the counter variable when removing, so that the new item which is now in the same spot as the removed one gets visited (the spot from which you just removed needs to get revisited).
- You probably want to `break` the inner loop after having found a duplicate, otherwise you compare and remove totally different items.
- <s>You have not made clear what the algorithm should do when there are more than 2 duplicate items of the same sort in the array. Leave one when their number is odd?</s> Thanks for your comment.
  To remove all existing duplicates, you will need to continue the search, but must not remove the `i`th element immediately or you won't have anything to compare to furtheron - or you might even remove the `i`th item multiple times (see #2).

So this modification should fit:

```
function removeAllDups(data) {
    // leaves only items in the array that appeared a single time
    // removes everything whose .number can be found multiple times
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var found = false,
            num = data[i].number;
        for (var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (data[j].number === num) {
                found = true;
                data.splice(j--, 1);
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            data.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: When a duplicate is found I want it to remove both instances of that duplicate. So for example say I have an array that looks like `code`[{name: "foo", number: 1}, {name:"bar", number: 2}, {name:"foo", number: 1}]`code` I would just want it to return `code`[{name: "bar", number: 2}]`code`

Comment: Sorry I just reread your response and realized I responded incorrectly to your last point. You just made me realize that one of my main issues is that in some cases I have 3 instances of an object and have not implemented anything to account for that. If there were 3 instances I would want all of them removed

Comment: Thanks a ton this works perfectly! However, I don't fully understand why you change the value of j and i inside the splice method. It seemed logical that you would need to splice the item at the index where data[j].number === num, then i and j would need to be reduced to account for the index that was removed.

Comment: Yes, that's just what this is doing. Notice that I've used `--` as a postfix operator, i.e. `splice()` will get passed the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate implementation. This uses only two passes through the array, and removes all dupes in cases > 2: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/1pdr780j/

```
function removeDupes(arr, test) {
    test = test || function(a, b) { return a === b; };

    function find(cache, element) {
        return cache.some(test.bind(null, element));
    }

    var seen = [];
    var dupes = [];
    var len = arr.length;
    var x;
    var current;

    // First pass - find dupes
    for (x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        current = arr[x];
        if (find(seen, current)) {
            dupes.push(current);
        } else {
            seen.push(current);
        }
    }

    // Second pass: remove dupes. Reverse iteration saves headaches here
    for (x = len - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        current = arr[x];
        if (find(dupes, current)) {
            arr.splice(x, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an updated version that takes an optional test function to determine equality for dupe purposes; for the OP's case, the call would be

```
removeDupes(arr, function(a, b) {
    return a.number == b.number;
});
```

Note that this assumes support for ES5 methods - `Array#some`, `Function#bind`. If you need to support older browsers, an ES5 shim or the Underscore library would fit the bill.

Comment: Notice that this works only for primitive values (in general: everything that can be cast to distinct strings). OP does test equality of the (object) items by their `.number` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`underscore.js`](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
function checkForDups(data) {
  return (
    _.map(
      _.filter(
        _.pairs(
          _.countBy(data)
        ), function(v) {return v[1] == 1}
      ), function(v) {return ~~v[0]}
    )
  )
}
```

### Example

```
>> console.log(checkForDups([0,1,2,3,0,1,0,4]))
[2, 3, 4]
```

You can try it [here](http://jsbin.com/giradoruhoha/1/edit?html,js,console).